# get child route parameters from root component(app.component)

Tags: angular, router

my gods:

How can I get child route parameters from app.component(the root component), In my application, the child route may be "/teaching/grade/1213" or "/part/sim/te/1232";
how can I get the param from app.component?

```
    ngOnInit() {

    this.router.events.subscribe(data => {
        // Only handle final active route
        if (data instanceof NavigationEnd) {
            // parsedUrl conatins params, queryParams 
            // and fragments for the active route
            let parsedUrl = this.router.parseUrl(data.url).root.children;

            console.log(parsedUrl.primary.segments);
        }
    });

}
```

In above code, has two question:
first: when then end component is active, then then subscribe is triggered;
second: "this.router.parseUrl(data.url)" would resolve the parameter as a route point;

please save me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.route.snapshot.params['id']

    // or

    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        console.log(params['id']);
    });
}
```

**2017/6/13 Update:**

1. Use shared data in service

**app-state.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class AppState {
  params = new BehaviorSubject(undefined);

  setParams(val: any) {
    this.params.next(val);
  }
}
```

**child.component.ts**

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private appState: AppState) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    this.appState.setParams(params['id']);
  });
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.appState.params.subscribe(val => {
    console.log(val);
  });
}
```

2. Try [ngrx/Store](https://github.com/ngrx/store)

Comment: all this return undefined, I think in root component, the activatedRoute is not the end(final) activatedRoute;

Comment: Can't you get it from this?
```let segments = parsedUrl.primary.segments;
segments[segments.length - 1].path```

Comment: thank you for answer my question. when I use this method, I fell so teriiable, I think this is not a better way to solve this question. otherwise, if the end router has no parameter?

Comment: The better one is to create a service, and store the shared data in it.
Or use `ngrx/store` to store state in `Store`

Comment: add a simple sample